Finding Minimum Hamming Distance
Given a set of vectors, $\{v_1, \dots, v_n \}$, I'd like to find their minimum Hamming Distance, $\min_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}|v_i - v_j|$. My main issue is, I don't know how to do this in Mathematica.
I know that I can first pick the index $1 \leq i \leq n-1$, then choose the second index $ i+1 \leq j \leq n$. In other programming languages (Python), I can use two for loops to help me, but I learned to not use for loops, and use instead Table and Do or other functions.
Here is my current code, with the problem area being the alldistances Table set-up.
(* Function to calculate the minimum Hamming distance of a set of vectors *)
minhammingdistance[vectors_] := Module[
  {alldistances, number, mindistance},
  (* Finds the number of vectors *)
  number = Length[vectors];
  (* Finds all distances *)
  alldistances = Table[
    HammingDistance[vectors[[i]], vectors[[j]]],
    {i, 1, n-1}, {j, i + 1, n}];
  (* Calculates minimum distance *)
  mindistance = Min[alldistances];
  (* Returns the minimum Hamming distance*)
  mindistance
]

I am grateful for any advice you can give on this issue!

Look in HammingDistance. to this end.

Try changing number to n in two places. Add Print[alldistances]; after the Table function. Is alldistances the result you expect?

If there are many vectors and efficiency is important, I would use Nearest with the 1-norm to create a NearestFunction object. Then apply it to all vectors to find the two closest. First will be the vector itself, next will be its nearest neighbor. Then find the pair that’s closest.

@creidhne this works! thank you!

@DanielLichtblau I'll try this one then. Is this the most efficient, you think?

It will likely be most efficient only if there are many vectors. How many? I don’t know. Possibly thousands.

For an example, I take 5 binary vectors of length 5:
    SeedRandom[4];
    dat = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {5, 5}];
    
    {{0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

To get all possible pairs, we may use "Subset":
Subsets[dat, {2}]

Now we only need to MapApply HammingDistance on these pairs:
HammingDistance @@@ Subsets[dat, {2}]

{4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3}

Finally, we take the minimum. All together in one line:
HammingDistance @@@ Subsets[dat, {2}] // Min

2


Thank you! Do you think this is the most efficient way to determine the minimum Hamming Distance?

Well, one can never be sure if not somebody has a bright idea. However, I think, you must check each pair and the built in "HammingDistance" is certainly faster than any  code in WL.
